# Streaming Netflix offline on Macbook using Windows

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, bootcamp, netflix

I've decided to install Windows 10 on my MacBook Air (256GB, 2019 Model) using bootcamp in order to stream Netflix offline using their app. I'll be downloading movies using their app, to watch them offline later.

I want to ask :

1. How much memory would be ideal to allocate to Windows for above usage?
2. Will I lose on video/audio quality? If yes, then how much? Will it be too terrible to drop this idea altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think by memory you mean disk space - that really depends on how many movies and other files you want to store at a time.

There should be no difference in video/audio quality. The only exception is if you're running something else that is so taxing on the computer that it is not able to play the video in real time. If that happens, close down the other programs while watching video. This is no different than when streaming Netflix on a PC.

Comment: Thank you so much. I allocated 60 Gb to it. I will only be streaming Netflix and will hardly store 2-3 movies at a time.

Comment: Sounds like plenty.